# Save experimental data within notebook. Is it possible?

Tags: data, dataset

I'm trying to use Mathematica for all my scientific needs as much as I can, so I can learn. When I want to plot my experimental data using Mathematica, I've been Import[] and plot data sets. However, in this case, if I need to work in different computer, I had to find both notebook file and data file, which is not convenient compared to other like OriginLab, Matlab and even Excel.

I certainly tried to find the solution, but I can find any simple and easy way. I can import and directly copy all points in notebook like below as I described, but most of time, the data have too many points, which makes it unpractical method.

Is there any easy and simple way to save experimental data points in Mathematica's notebook? So, the notebook is the only thing we need when we need to execute and analyze data. I know there is few methods to save data as different file format (like aaa.mx file), but what I am hopping for is one united notebook with which data set are saved.

I've been doing this very crude way.

[image]

Then, expand all data and copy them in notebook as data to save them within notebook.

```
data = {{17.3913`, 0.000199`}, {17.33102`, 0.000136`}, {17.27116`, 
   0.000215`}, {17.24138`, 0.000128`}, {17.18213`, 
   0.00011`}, {17.12329`, 1.14`}, {17.06485`, 0.273`}, {17.0068`, 
   0.0001`}, {16.94915`, 0.0001`},....{2.004`, 89.02206`}, {2.003`, 88.95633`}, {2.002`, 
   88.83745`}, {2.001`, 88.81386`}, {2, 88.73096`}};

ListLinePlot[data]
```

This is an example data set, if you want to see.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvnj604lam9bffu/UVvisNIR%20and%20FTIR_test.csv?dl=0

Any thoughts, solutions and suggestion will be very appreciable. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97498).

Comment: Another place is [saving data inside notebook](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39076/keep-data-in-memory-inside-a-notebook-without-having-to-evaluate-it-again)

Comment: @ J.M. Thank you for your suggestion. I find my need there. [link](http://fonseca.info/myftpdirectory/withContextDump1.2.nb)

Comment: Also strongly related: "[Storing data in the Notebook in readable form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23124/280)."